# Node.js hosting platform Heroku-like

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I want to create something similar to Heroku (first I was thinking in EngineYard-like but I prefer Heroku) for node.js (I know they already support node.). However, It's for a personal project so it doesn't need to be anything overcomplicated or super expensive. I believe I can learn a lot creating a product like this.

Before I start, I have several doubts:

- Heroku uses a reverse proxy to receive the requests. However, reverse proxy doesn't work fine with websockets. How can this be fixed?
- 1 instance supports several dynos. How can an instance be divided by RAM, processing, etc?
- I guess if I have an answer to the last questions I'll be able to create a route mesh. However, what can be the tricks here?

Regards.
Donalds

Comment: Nodester.... it really rocks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the simplest possible implementation.

- Use HAProxy, Apache Traffic Server or
  mongrel2 as your reverse proxy.  They
  all support the HTTP 1.1 protocol and
  should work with websockets.
- Don't worry about limiting resources.
- Also don't worry about a routing mesh. 
  Just update and reload the 
  config on your reverse proxy any time 
  you're spinning up a backend process.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

### So you want to be a node Paas?

Nodejitsu opensourced their hosting solution: [haibu](https://github.com/nodejitsu/haibu) (Japanese for Hive). It's well documented and you'll also get real time support if you hope onto #nodejitsu on efnet irc network.

As a user of their service, I can vouch for the simplicity of the solution. You use their client [jitsu](https://github.com/nodejitsu/jitsu) to provision, configure and deploy the applications. Applications are watched over by their tweaked version of [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever).